# How can I give percentage in React-Native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to give padding to a vector-icon but it doesn't work when I try to give it with the percentage
[image]

Comment: Define *doesn't work*, please.

Comment: As you can see "container" has padding of 10% but it doesn't appear on the screen. Only when I change it to dp than it works.